# Using calendar_date_select with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to create a user date-of-birth selection field during sign up.
The code looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
<h3>Register</h3>  
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div style="width: 374px; margin: 0 auto;">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <%= f.label :dob %>
      <%= f.calendar_date_select "e_date" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I try to load it, rails gives me this error:

```
undefined method `calendar_date_select' for #<#<Class:0x00000101210208>:0x0000010120d0a8>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** I installed the calendar_date_select gem using:
    gem install calendar_date_select
I'm running OS X Snow Leopard if it matters.

Comment: Did you install the calendar_date_select gem?

Answer (score 9):

1. Add to Gemfile:

   `gem 'calendar_date_select', :git => 'git://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git'`

   Don't use the rails3test branch it is old and was [previously](https://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select/commit/977048211b94599fe0f08eb37a481f3d69df48f6) merged into master
2. run `bundle install`
3. run `rake calendar:install`
4. Add `<%= calendar_date_select_includes %>` AFTER `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults%>` in your layout
5. Add `<%= f.calendar_date_select "calendar" %>` to your view

Comment: shouldn't all executables (such as rake) be run using bundle exec?  http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/

Comment: after doing this you should restart the server aswell. At least I got it to work like that after completing the instructions above.