# Getting CalendarDateSelect gem to work with Rails 3

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

When I follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979495/using-calendar-date-select-with-rails-3/4512839#4512839) and run `bundle install`, I get:

```
Fetching http://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git
c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:560:in ``': No such file or directory - git clone "http://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git" "c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/calendar_date_select-32215bd0f96918494c96e788d776d90837363fe4" --bare --no-hardlinks (Errno::ENOENT)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I can see the GIT repository I want at `https://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select/tree/rails3test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this by the way.  That error message (``` ``': No such file or directory ```) was obfuscating the real problem, which was that `git` *wasn't on my PATH*.  Hmm.

Comment: Happened for me when I had just installed git but hadn't restarted my iTerm sessions.

Answer (score 0):

So far I am running into problems on Panques version it worked before but now doesn't.  I think the best option would probably to use JQuery's datepicker as it won't be bound to a Rails version and is stable.

Comment: yeah, I've since updated my site to jQuery anyway so the problem is now moot!