# rails upgrade from version 2 to 3. undefined method `calendar_date_select_includes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-3-upgrade

I'm using the calendar_date_select gem.

It was working fine in my rails 2.3.x versions.

But now I am trying to upgrade it to 3.0.10

Really stuck on error `undefined method 'calendar_date_select_includes'` for all pages.

Gemfile just has:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.11'
gem "acts_as_list"
gem "simple_form"
gem "calendar_date_select"
gem "haml"
```

My views/layouts/application.html.haml page has this (Note: haml !)

```
%head
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'contam/default.scss'
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'main.css'
  = javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"
  = javascript_include_tag "jQueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"
  %script
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  = javascript_include_tag :defaults
  = calendar_date_select_includes "silver"
```

Also my styles are not being loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the official Calendar Date Select gem is still not Rails 3 ready, as [discussed in a previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979495/using-calendar-date-select-with-rails-3/4512839#4512839).

However, a [fork provided by paneq](https://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select) does support Rails 3, so if you change your Gemfile from

```
gem "calendar_date_select"
```

to

```
gem 'calendar_date_select', :git => 'http://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git'
```

it should get you back up and running. I haven't personally used CDS in Rails 3, instead I migrated to [formtastic](http://rubygems.org/gems/formtastic) and [formtastic_datepicker_inputs](http://rubygems.org/gems/formtastic_datepicker_inputs) which requires jQueryUI's date picker.

Comment: Yes that worked.  I had found a link saying have `:version = 'rails3test'` or something at the end of the same line of code (which did work) but I removed it per your shorter version and rebundled and that worked too which is good.

Comment: Good to also know about the formtastic helper.  Presumably that means I'll be able to use it in simple_form which is built on top of formtastic then. :)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Originally paneq had the changes on the rails3test branch, but apparently merged them into master, so good to know they both work :)

Comment: I would guess that the formtastic datepicker helpers would work with simple_form, but I haven't used simple_form much less attempted to test that guess :)

Comment: I had the same problem and it was fixed by adding th github url, but now I couldn't deploy it to my server using capistrano, any ideas?